# Erlang exclude type from supertype

Tags: types, erlang

In Erlang, is it possible to define a type by excluding a subtype from a supertype? As an example, how would I define a type that is "anything but `pid()`":

```erlang
-type anything_but_pid() :: ...?
```

Reading the docs on supervisor data types, I came across [this](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#type-child_id) type spec for `child_id()`, which defines the type as `term()`, and then says `Not a pid()` in a comment below:

> `child_id() = term()`
>
> Not a `pid()`.

Is that the best I can do if I don't want to explicitly list all possible types?

Comment: The BNF for the type syntax can be found here: http://www2.erlang.se/documentation/doc-8.2/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of OTP 23 (and even 24) this is not supported.

Moreover, expecting Dialyzer to help is such cases is ill-advised, as Dialyzer is often over-approximating, for several reasons, and although I don't think that it would turn such a type to `term()` immediately, it might very well do so at the first given opportunity (e.g. wherever you call such a function).

Comment: Indeed. It is good for people to keep in mind that Dialyzer is a "success typer" not a strict typer.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible workaround for this you may define a specification for your function like this:

```erlang
    -spec foo(pid()) -> ...;
             (any()) -> ...
    foo(data) when is_pid(data) -> error;
    foo(data) -> ....
```

Comment: thanks! that's definitely an option (at least for inbuilt types). preferably I'd like Dialyzer to catch invalid function calls instead of adding a clause just to handle invalid inputs.

Comment: This won't work, as such overloaded (i.e. multi-clause) specs cannot have overlapping domains; such specs are currently unsupported and are simply ignored (warning copied straight from expanding the given example to a small test module).

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for `anything_but_pid()`, you could "simply" enumerate all other options:

```
-type anything_but_pid() :: port()
                          | reference()
                          | atom()
                          | bitstring()
                          | number()
                          | fun()
                          | maybe_improper_list()
                          | map()
                          | tuple()
```

Of course, this doesn't generalize...